# Outlook meeting invitation sending using php not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using `ical_library` for generating meeting invitation and it is generating a code:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Sabre//Sabre VObject 4.1.0//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:sabre-vobject-4b0105a1-bac5-4068-bd65-b4581d3497c4
DTSTAMP:20160602T081647Z
SUMMARY:Training Schedule Invitation
DTSTART:2016-06-03 09:00:00
DTEND:2016-06-03 10:00:00
LOCATION:Bangalore
ATTENDEE:ragesh@ascent-online.net
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

But When I sent this code as the content of the mail, it is not converting to an invitation.

The same code is getting displayed. I'm using `codeigniter` email library for sending the email.

Comment: Your iCalendar data is invalid in various different ways. DTSTART, DTEND, ATTENDEE are all wrong. It's missing REQUEST and ORGANIZER..

Answer (score -1):

```
private function sendCalEntry( $tsStart, $tsEnd, $location, $summary, $title, $resources, $to, $subject ){

    $from = ORGANISATIONREPLYMAIL;
    $dtstart = date('Ymd',$tsStart).'T'.date('His',$tsStart);
    $dtend = date('Ymd',$tsEnd).'T'.date('His',$tsEnd);
    $loc = $location;

    $vcal = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\r\n";
    $vcal .= "VERSION:2.0\r\n";
    $vcal .= "PRODID:-//nonstatics.com//OrgCalendarWebTool//EN\r\n";
    $vcal .= "METHOD:REQUEST\r\n";
    $vcal .= "BEGIN:VEVENT\r\n";
    $vcal .= "ORGANIZER;CN=\"".ORGANISATIONNAME." (".$_SESSION['username'].")"."\":mailto:".ORGANISATIONREPLYMAIL."\r\n";
    $vcal .= "UID:".date('Ymd').'T'.date('His')."-".rand()."-nonstatics.com\r\n";
    $vcal .= "DTSTAMP:".date('Ymd').'T'.date('His')."\r\n";
    $vcal .= "DTSTART:$dtstart\r\n";
    $vcal .= "DTEND:$dtend\r\n"; 
    $vcal .= "LOCATION:$location\r\n";
    $vcal .= "SUMMARY:$summary\r\n";
    $vcal .= "DESCRIPTION:Hinweis/Fahrer:$summary - Folgende Resourcen wurden gebucht: $resources \r\n";
    $vcal .= "BEGIN:VALARM\r\n";
    $vcal .= "TRIGGER:-PT15M\r\n";
    $vcal .= "ACTION:DISPLAY\r\n";
    $vcal .= "DESCRIPTION:Reminder\r\n";
    $vcal .= "END:VALARM\r\n";
    $vcal .= "END:VEVENT\r\n";
    $vcal .= "END:VCALENDAR\r\n";

    $headers = "From: $from\r\nReply-To: $from"; 
    $headers .= "\r\nMIME-version: 1.0\r\nContent-Type: text/calendar; name=calendar.ics; method=REQUEST; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"";
    $headers .= "\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\nX-Mailer: Microsoft Office Outlook 12.0"; 

    return @mail($to, $subject . " " . $summary . " / " . $resources, $vcal, $headers);
}
```

http://blog.sebastian-martens.de/2012/01/submit-outlook-calendar-invitations-with-php/

Comment: No.I'm using codeigniter mail with protocol as SMTP. I can't do this with php mail function.So can you provide an example with codeigniter email library?

Answer (score -1):

### When I validate the ICS data online it returns the following errors:

---

***Errors***

> Invalid DTSTART value, must be a date or date-time value near line # 5
>
> Reference: RFC 5545 3.3.5. Date-Time
>
> Invalid DTEND value, must be a date or date-time value near line # 5
>
> Reference: RFC 5545 3.3.5. Date-Time

---

### My solution

---

I had issues with this too and ended up sending the ics file as an attachment in code igniter:

```
$this->email->attach($ics_data_as_string, 'attachment', $name_for_ics_file_in_email, 'text/calendar');
```

---

Hopefully this helps.